# How to display the ContextMenuStrip when item is selected in a list box c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, contextmenustrip, listboxitems

I'm trying select an item from list box when is right clicked and show the ContextMenuStrip to display my options available, but when I click everywhere in the control (list box) is showing the ContextMenuStrip.

This is what I have in code:

```
private void lbSMTPEmails_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{       
       int SelectedIndex = lbSMTPEmails.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

       if (SelectedIndex == -1)
            lbSMTPEmails.ContextMenuStrip.Hide();            
        else
        {
            lbSMTPEmails.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;
            lbSMTPEmails.ContextMenuStrip.Show();
        }
}
```

do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This code is working for me ! when i selected any item in listbox it is showing me contextmenustrip and when you click inside listbox (not select any item again) then it is not showing contextmenustrip for me!

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, I found another solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `opening` event of `ContextMenuStrip`

```
void cms_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int SelectedIndex = lbSMTPEmails.IndexFromPoint( lbSMTPEmails.PointToClient(Cursor.Position) );

   if (SelectedIndex == -1)
        e.Cancel = true;        
    else
    {
        lbSMTPEmails.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did by this way and it worked!

```
private void listbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ShowMenuStrip = listbox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location) >= 0; //This is a global bool variable

    if (ShowMenuStrip)
       listbox.SelectedIndex = listbox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    else
       listbox.SelectedIndex = -1;          
}

private void ContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !ShowMenuStrip;
}
```